# Receive an http post from an external server with servlet

Tags: java, servlets, http-post, server-to-server

on my public web application running on JBoss 5 with Java 6 I need to implement something that receive an http post from another external server with some parameters (server to server call) .
The server that call me doesn't need an answer, just standard http code reponse( es 200 - OK). 
Can I use a servlet for this?
If not what should I use? (I cant'use restfull or soap ws).

Comment: Based on the little bit of information you've given it sounds possible.  A servlet should be able to handle any content type so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, your best bet for given situation is REST or SOAP. But you already mentioned that you cannot use that.
I don't see any reason why a servlet can't be used here. You have request & response objects in servlet doPost method. You can manipulate the response object to set appropriate response code back.